# On the proof of ultrafilter theorem.

Tags: filters

I was self studying some model theory and found [this](https://dra.american.edu/islandora/object/thesesdissertations:445) article which suited my interests. Now, I completed reading upto the ultrafilter lemma in this article. Actually I didn't understand the proof mentioned in this article.
This lemma is in page 12 of the article. I actually didn't get two points made in this article. Let $F$ be a filter.

$(1)$- If $\mathscr{\widetilde{F}}$ is the collection of all proper filters than contain $F$, then it claims that $\mathscr{\widetilde{F}}$ is non empty because $F\in\mathscr{\widetilde{F}}$. Now, how it's true if $F$ isn't a proper filter as $F$ was generally called as filter?

$(2)$- If $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain. How is $\cup{\mathscr{C}}$ a upper bound for $\mathscr{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

(1) By "proper" filter is meant a filter which does not contain the empty set. Usually, this is part of definition of the filter, and the term "proper" just serves to emphasize this particular property (though notions differ slightly in literature). Certainly, $F$ is assumed to be such a proper filter for the assertion (otherwise the assertion cannot be correct).

(2) You have to show that $G=\bigcup\mathscr C$ is a (proper) filter, that is, an element of $\widetilde{\mathscr F}$ (because it contains $F$). Once you have shown this, it is clear that it is an upper bound: If $C\in\mathscr C$, then $C\subseteq G$ by definition of $G$, that is $C\preceq G$ with respect to the partial order $\preceq$ given by the inclusion.

The proof that $G$ is indeed a (proper) filter is straightforward: Just verify the filter axioms (and $\emptyset\notin G$) by using that every element in $\mathcal C$ is a (proper) filter and that $\mathcal C$ is a chain.

Comment: Sir is $F\in\cup{\mathscr{C}}$?

Comment: Yes, because every $C\in\mathscr C$ belongs to $\widetilde{\mathscr F}$ and so, by definition, $F\in C$. Thus (since $\mathscr C$ contains at least one element $C$, because it is a chain), $F\in\bigcup\mathscr C$.

Comment: I think you mean $F \subseteq \bigcup C$ and $F \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{C}$?

Comment: @Mark Kamsma, Isn't it possible that some chain $C$ may have $F\in C$?

Comment: @Martin Väth, I actually am confused with this proof a lot. Sir, I request another proof of it (Possibly in your style).

Comment: @Rahul I noticed a typo in my previous comment, it should be "$F \subseteq C$ and $F \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{C}$". For a chain $\mathscr{C}$ we could definitely have $F \in \mathscr{C}$, which implies that $F \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{C}$. The latter will always happen (and that is what is important for this lemma), because of the reason Martin Väth explained (albeit with wrong notation). That is, $\mathscr{C}$ is non-empty, so there is $C \in \mathscr{C}$ and by definition $F \subseteq C$ so $F \subseteq C \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{C}$.

Comment: @Mark Kamsma, Exactly that's what I wanted. But  in the proof that I mentioned in the link uses $\in$ instead of $\subseteq$

Comment: @Rahul The proof in the link actually completely skips the step to show that $F \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{C}$. It does talk about elements of $\bigcup \mathscr{C}$, named $A$ and $B$, to show that it is again a filter (see point (2) in Martin's answer). That part of the linked proof seems correct to me.

Comment: @MarkKamsma: I deleted my previous wrong comments, because by mistake I thought that $F$ is a subset of the underlying set and not a filter. You are right: One should replace $F\subseteq C$ and $F\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr C$ in my first comment. (Reason for my confusion: The notion “contains $F$” can be interpreted in two ways. Of course, in the assertion it should mean “contains $F$ as a subset” [because $F$ is a filter].)

Comment: For completeness, here is a fixed version of the first comment: Every $C\in\mathcal C$ belongs to $\widetilde{\mathscr F}$ and so, by definition, $F\subseteq C$. Thus (since $\mathscr C$ contains at least one element $C$, because it is a chain), $F\subseteq\bigcup_{C\in\mathscr C}C=\bigcup\mathscr C$.